# Mostrar datos con inputs con conexión PDO

Tags: php, pdo

```
  **Esta parte es el php donde realizo la consulta para llamar los datos el id es que aparece al principio es una variable que compara para que busque ese registro y lo muestre en el formulario**


 <?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$producto = "";
$precio = "";
$cantidad ="";

$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eladeria", "root", "");
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if ($_POST) {
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM ventas where Id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(['id'=>$id]);
    $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $producto = $arrDatos['producto'];
    $cantidad = $arrDatos['cantidad'];
    $precio = $arrDatos['precio'];
}

?>




**en esta parte esta el formulario donde quiero mostrar los datos del php en los input**



 <form method="post" action="categoriaactualizar.php" id="formulario">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label class='control-sidebar-subheading' for="fecha">Id</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="id" id="id" required maxlength="255"
                                                           class="form-control" readonly value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label class='control-sidebar-subheading'
                                                           for="fecha">Producto</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required
                                                           maxlength="255" class="form-control"
                                                           value="<?php echo $producto; ?>"/>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label class='control-sidebar-subheading'
                                                           for="fecha">Cantidad</label>
                                                    <input type="number" name="limite_credito" id="limite_credito"
                                                           required maxlength="255" class="form-control"
                                                           value="<?php echo $cantidad; ?>"/>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label class='control-sidebar-subheading' for="fecha">Precio</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" required
                                                           maxlength="255" class="form-control"
                                                           value="<?php echo $precio; ?>"/>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label class='control-sidebar-subheading' for="fecha">Fecha</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" required
                                                           maxlength="255" class="form-control"
                                                           value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>"/>
                                                </div>


                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <br>
                                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"
                                                           disabled/>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
```

Comment: ya investigue pero no tengo una refencia clara como puedo hacer para mostrar los datos en inputs con conexion pdo

Comment: Cual es el problema que tienes, que error te da ?

Comment: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: id in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\AdminLTE-master\vistas\editar_venta.php</b> on line <b>360</b><br />

Comment: me tira ese error pero es que no se si tengo bien el procedimiento del php

Comment: Lo que pasa es que debes inicializar las variables antes de tu condición

Comment: lo hice ahorita actualice la edición pero me tira lo mismo

Comment: Debes de inicializarlas afuera del `if ($_POST) {`

Comment: Ahorita lo hice pero no me tira ningun error probé metiendo valores y me los muestra pero traídos desde la base de datos no

Comment: intenta agregar esto, echo '<input class="text" type="text" id="producto" name="producto" value="'. $producto .'">'; antes del cierre de la etiqueta  ´?>´  y avisa que imprime

Comment: no me tira ningun error nada me tira el input en blanco

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de organizar un poco mejor tu pregunta explicando qué es lo que te ocurre, qué error te da y dónde.

Veo varios errores, haces un `fetchAll` de la variable `$busqueda`, sin embargo la variable $busqueda nunca se ha inicializado (Por lo menos en la porción de código que muestras).

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT *  FROM ventas where id=" . $id);
$arrDatos = $busqueda->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Hacer lo que haces en la línea anterior `id` = `$id` es un error de seguridad GRAVISIMO, la variable `$id` viene de un `GET` modificable por el usuario, el cual podría ejecutar directamente sentencias `SQL` a la base de datos, ya que estas usando sentencias preparadas, deberías usarlas correctamente, tal que así:

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT *  FROM ventas WHERE id = :id);
$stmt->execute(['id'=>$id]);
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Si te fijas, no he colocado la variable directamente, si no que la estoy pasando una vez preparada la sentencia. Tampoco hago referencia a la variable $busqueda, ahora se hace referencia a $stmt.

Te recomiendo que te pases por [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/53134)

Comment: entiendo gracias por eso lo tendre en cuenta

Comment: @user9472850 ¡Genial! Prueba y si tu pregunta quedó solucionada, marcarla como resuelta :)

Comment: mm bueno hice lo que me sugeriste pero ahora edite la edicion pero no me muestra los datos en los inputs no tengo conexion y no se si es por que tengo mala la sintaxis o alfo del php

Comment: ya tengo conexion  lo que hice fue sacar la conexion del  if($_post) pero no me esta asignando los datos alas variables no me trae los datos  de la base de datos

Comment: Revisa que los campos estén bien escritos, que exista el dato realmente en la tabla, que el nombre de la tabla sea el correcto. Además me parece que no tienes activados los errores de PHP, pásate por aquí https://www.anerbarrena.com/mostrar-errores-php-608/